# div having three child div's inside css issue

Tags: html, css

Im preparing website page structure but stuck here

Html

```
<div id="main">
   <div id="left"></div>
   <div id="content"></div>
   <div id="right"></div
</div>
```

css

```
#main
{
  background: url("../images/bkg_main1.gif") no-repeat scroll 50% 0 #FBFAF6;
  width: 100%;
}
#left
{
  float:left;
}
#content
{
  width:997px;
  margin:0 auto;
}
#right
{
  float:right;
}
```

left div should appear in the left side of page it is appearing and the content div should appear in the middle, it is also appearing in the middle and right div should appear in the right side of page. The right div is appearing in the right side of page but it is appearing at the right-bottom corner.

Comment: #main is too small ;) As #main is set by the window width, making the window too small to hold the content will result in #right dropping underneath. Pop some border:1px solid #f0f; around your divs to see what they're up to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way

```
<div id="main">
   <div id="left"></div>
    <div id="right"></div>
   <div id="content"></div>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put both floated divs (left and right) before the content.

Also, you should define a width for the floated elements, and a left and right margin for the content (equal to the width) or the float can 'fall down' if it gets big enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
#left, #content, #right {
    float: left;
}
```